# Show AJAX content after images have loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, image, load

I am developing my own lightbox kind of jquery plugin.  Everything works but I want to hide the loaded content until the images have loaded in the browser from the AJAX call. I found a similar post and I am using the following script but the setTimeout function is what reveals the content and not the .load function.  Am I trying to achieve the impossible?

```
$.ajax({
      url: 'meet/'+ pLoad + '.html',  
      success: function(data) {
        var imageCount = $(data).filter('img').length;
        var imagesLoaded = 0;
        $(data).hide()
         .appendTo('#zoom_inner')
         .filter('img')
         .load( function() {
          ++imagesLoaded;
          if (imagesLoaded >= imageCount) {
          $('#zoom_inner').children().show();
          }
          });
        setTimeout( function() { $('#zoom_inner').children().show() }, 5000 );
       }
    });
```

Comment: Can you please high-light your code and press the 'code' button (button with 1's and 0's) in the editor's toolbar for us?

Comment: Sorry about that...  The setTimeout function is there incase the load function doesn't work.  Which is definitely the case...  Here is a working demo, http://dev.alcostores.com/abt_career_meet.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding your comments:

data is just a string in your success callback  - it's "html", but it's a string.

make it a node to use:

```
var $images = $(data); // i.e. turn <div><img /></div> into a div with an img as a child or whatever you got
var imageCount = $images.find('img').length;
```

cool, eh?

Comment: Have you tested any variables? is imageCount getting the right count? is imagesLoaded increasing? even `alert(imagesLoaded);` after the `++imagesLoaded;` would be helpful to verify.

Comment: doing that now and imageCount isn't incrementing past 0

Troubleshooting that now.  Any ideas why that wouldn't $(data).filter('img').length; would only return 0

Comment: THanks Dan, I arrived at a similar solution - $(data).hide().appendTo('#zoom_inner');               var images = document.getElementById("zoom_inner").getElementsByTagName('img');

Comment: Could be rewritten as `$('#zoom_inner').append( $(data).hide() ).find('img');` for the sake of jQuery coolness :p

Comment: This doesn't prove the image has loaded 100% in the browser, see jQuery load() function, even that isn't 100% crossbrowser safe. As far as I know there isn't really any good way of doing this yet with ajax. This should however indicate that the image has started to load at least.